# What to say when we put the dishes on the table for people to eat after cooking?

Tags: word-choice, ambiguity

OK, after cooking food, we have to put the dishes on the table for people to eat.

> ## **[set](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/set)** 1
>
> /set/  verb (past tense and past participle *set*, present
>   participle *setting*)
>
> 1 **PUT** [transitive always + adverb/preposition] written to carefully
>   put something down somewhere
>
> **set something (down) on something**
>
> She set the tray down on a table next to his bed.
>
> Mark filled the pan and set it on the stove.
>
> **set something down/aside**
>
> The workmen set the box down carefully on the floor.
>
> Remove the mushrooms and set them aside.
>
> *Longman Dictionary*

---

> ## **[prepare](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prepare?q=prepare)**
>
> 3. [transitive] **prepare something** to make food ready to be eaten
>
> He was in the kitchen preparing lunch.
>
> *Oxford Learner's Dictionary*

Do we say "**to set** the dishes on the table" or "**to prepare** the dishes on the table"?

Comment: You have the answer in the dictionary definitions. "set the dishes" and "prepare the dishes" have two different meanings. The first is similar to *laying the table* the second means *cooking food*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more idiomatic and common to say  “set the table” as in

> Rebecca's mother told her **to set the table** for lunch.

Setting a table includes placing the ***plates*** (also called *dishes*), cutlery (US *flatware*), glasses, napkins, bread etc. on the table.

*Prepare the dishes* suggest *cooking* = *preparing* two or more different food preparations such as pasta, curry, fajitas, wagashi etc. *To prepare a meal* means to cook a meal, usually from scratch.

> He spent all day **preparing a romantic meal**

From Oxford Learner's Dictionary

> ## **[dish](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dish_1?q=dish)**
>
> 1. a flat shallow container for cooking food in or serving it from
>
>    - *They helped themselves from a large dish [plate] of pasta.*
> 2. **the dishes** [plural] the plates, bowls, cups, etc. that have been used for a meal and need to be washed
>
>    - *I'll do the dishes*
> 3. [countable] food prepared in a particular way as part of a meal
>
>    - *a vegetarian/fish dish*

Answer (score 0):

*Set the table* and *lay the table* are both set phrases to describe this action; you don't need to specify 'the dishes'. The two have been compared [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233926/set-the-table-or-lay-the-table)